# My first NUXT.js app is refusing to run on localhost:3000

Tags: localhost, nuxt.js

l recently installed nuxt.js on my local machine and created a new project that when l run npm run dev, it saying the project is listening on http://localhost:3000 but upon clicking to that the connection is not going through and its saying the message below

This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Did you mean http://localhost3000.org/?
Search Google for localhost 3000
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Something running on that port already? Have you tried to specify another port?

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is to write this in your `package.json`

```
    "config": {
        "nuxt": {
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "port": "3000"
        }
    },
```

This is because that `0.0.0.0` means all `ipv4` address in your server. however, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are not.